# upvotes on review audits are not applied

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, upvotes

I noticed that upvotes on review audits are not applied.

For example, I just was audited for this review:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4628550
In my opinion, this clearly should have an upvote. It already had 12, but that is not relevant in my opinion. In these cases, I usually open the question, find the answer and upvote it anyway.

Please apply upvotes on review audits.

Comment: I was surprised to learn that this was the way things worked as well. I suspect that has to do with another related review process. I say that because I've noticed on 'test' questions which dredge up formerly reviewed questions/answers, once you've voted, it then shows the 'review' vote. Visiting the question itself, you see the 'user' vote, which is ofcourse usually different. I wonder if reviews that are down voted are shuttled off into another queue for further review, and this is the reason for the separation.

Comment: The trouble with this IMO is if you've got a post that is -5 and "known" to be bad and would have disappeared off everyone's radar forever, is it really fair to start drawing a load of additional attention to it so it harbours another 5 downvotes? Same goes for positive audits, if a post was worthy of +5, should being selected for audit be a fair reason to boost it to +10, when the post was almost certainly of no use to the reviewers at that point in time? (I'm assuming that audits are reused)

Comment: @OGHaza I see your point. However, when I think an answer deserves an upvote because I think it is a good answer, I will upvote it. It does not matter to me how many upvotes it has, or how I encountered it (through searching for an answer to my problem, or review). Downvoting answers will cost you rep, so I'd rather flag them.

Comment: Found this myself just a moment ago.  Now I just have a mental note that when this happens, I should click BACK, open the link to full question, and upvote.  A little extra effort but not insurmountable (as long as you KNOW the problem exists!).