# Is it intentional that undoing a vote is recorded in an audit?

Tags: support, status-norepro, review-audits, undo

I've read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251653/upvotes-on-review-audits-are-not-applied) that votes on audits aren't recorded.

The post in this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26787937 have been upvoted by me a long time ago. I decided to test the theory that votes aren't recorded in audits, so I undid my upvote.

When I went to check the post, the vote was in fact undid (I put the upvote back).

Is it intentional that *undoing* a vote (that was casted long before) is recorded in an audit?

Comment: A long time ago? That question is only 25 days old! And you've only been a member for 2 months. That's not a long time...

Comment: @PM2Ring Everything is relative.

Answer (score 9):

Negative. You can't vote in a Triage review.

If you have a userscript that enables you to vote in Triage, the vote or unvote will definitely be applied to the actual post itself.

---

If you see voting buttons after completing an audit, well it ceases to be a faked post, and the actual post and actual score is then displayed to you. Whatever action you take after that is on the actual post.

This is different from the post you linked ([upvotes on review audits are not applied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251653)), as that is referring to voting while one has yet to complete the audit.

Comment: I don't have a userscript.

Comment: Then I'm curious to know how did you undo your vote in Triage when there's no voting buttons.

Comment: It's an audit. When we get Congratulations!, the button shows.